# Duplicated thumbnail images inside php image sprite

Tags: php, sprite, gd, bounding-box

I'm working on linux, xampp and wordpress testing theme with style.css and index.php.

I created php script using **GD** library that creates **image sprite**. It can conditionally creates sprite from given folder(glob), or from urls (array). It also scale all thumbnails in the fly to fit a given bounding box(not my function).

My problem is that all thumbnails are duplicated inside next thumbnails. Like: First image is duplicated in 2, 2 in 3, 3 in 4(...). However proper image is always on top of duplicated image.

I think my loop or merging thumbnail have problems, but I'm not sure.

Here is my code (by default creates sprite from array):

```
<?php

//////// PART 1 - DEFINE GLOBAL VARIABLES ////////

//// SPRITE IMAGES SOURCE ////
// 0 = Create sprite from memory - array()
// 1 = Create sprite from folder - glob()
$sprite_images_source = 0;

//// Use array as sprite images source ////
if($sprite_images_source == 0){
  $images=array(
    //// Example .PNGs ////
    // Orientation: Horizontal, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/128x72/444/f2f2f2.png&text=128x72.png',
    // Orientation: Horizontal, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/444/f2f2f2.png&text=1280x720.png',
    // Orientation: Vertical, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/72x128/444/f2f2f2.png&text=72x128.png',
    // Orientation: Vertical, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/720x1280/444/f2f2f2.png&text=720x1280.png',
    // Square, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/200x200/444/f2f2f2.png&text=400x400.png',

    //// Example .JPEGs ////
    // Orientation: Horizontal, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/128x72/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=128x72.jpg',
    // Orientation: Horizontal, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=1280x720.jpg',
    // Orientation: Vertical, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/72x128/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=72x128.jpg',
    // Orientation: Vertical, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/720x1280/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=720x1280.jpg',
    // Square
    'https://dummyimage.com/200x200/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=200x200.jpg',

    //// Example .GIFs ////
    // Orientation: Horizontal, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/128x72/888/f2f2f2.gif&text=128x72.gif',
    // Orientation: Horizontal, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/888/f2f2f2.gif&text=1280x720.gif',
    // Orientation: Vertical, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/72x128/888/f2f2f2.gif&text=72x128.gif',
    // Try to have 1/3/5/7 images to see empty space on sprite,
    // and test colorize sprite background method with this

  );

//// Use folder as sprite images source ////
} else if($sprite_images_source == 1){
 // $images = glob('sprite/images/*');
}


//// SINGLE THUMBNAIL = BOUNDING BOX DIMENSIONS ////
$thumbnail_width = 300;
$thumbnail_height = 300;
$thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);


//// SPRITE DIMENSIONS ////
$sprite_columns = 5;
$sprite_rows = ceil(count($images) / $sprite_columns);
$sprite_width = $thumbnail_width * $sprite_columns;
$sprite_height = $thumbnail_height * $sprite_rows;
$sprite = imagecreatetruecolor($sprite_width, $sprite_height);


//// SPRITE BACKGROUND COLOR ////
$sprite_bg = imagecolortransparent($sprite, imagecolorallocatealpha($sprite, 0,0,0,0));
imagefill($sprite,0,0,$sprite_bg);


//////// PART 2 - GENERATE SPRITE ////////

//// Assign each source from array to single image
foreach ($images as $i => $image) {
  $images[$i] = array(
    'src' => $image,
    'title' => 'Product ' . ($i + 1),
    'price' => '$' . ($i * 100)
  );
}


//// SINGLE THUMBNAIL MANIPULATION ////
// Start Generate Thumbnail from first file in array/folder
$i = 0;

for ($y = 0; $y < $sprite_height; $y += $thumbnail_height) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < $sprite_width; $x += $thumbnail_width) {
    // What is this for ???
    if ($i >= count($images)) {
      break 2;
    }

    // Assosiate correct image for thumbnail from array
    $image = $images[$i];
    $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image['src']));

    // Scale Image to Bounding Box
    scale_image($src, $thumbnail, 'fit');


    //// PRINT IMAGE INTO SINGLE THUMBNAIL ////
    imagecopy($sprite, $thumbnail, $x, $y, 0, 0, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
    imagedestroy($src);
    $i++;
  }
  // END | for ($y = 0; $y < $sprite_height; $y += $thumbnail_height)
}
// END | for ($y = 0; $y < $sprite_height; $y += $thumbnail_height)


//////// PART 3 - OUTPUT SPRITE ////////

// Output Sprite to Browser as PNG
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($sprite);

// Clean up, and free memory
imagedestroy($thumbnail);
imagedestroy($sprite);


// FUNCTION - SCALE IMAGE
function scale_image($src_image, $dst_image, $op = 'fit') {
  $src_width = imagesx($src_image);
  $src_height = imagesy($src_image);

  $dst_width = imagesx($dst_image);
  $dst_height = imagesy($dst_image);

  // Try to match destination image by width
  $new_width = $dst_width;
  $new_height = round($new_width*($src_height/$src_width));
  $new_x = 0;
  $new_y = round(($dst_height-$new_height)/2);

  // FILL and FIT mode are mutually exclusive
  if ($op =='fill')
    $next = $new_height < $dst_height;
  else
    $next = $new_height > $dst_height;

  // If match by width failed and destination image does not fit, try by height
  if ($next) {
    $new_height = $dst_height;
    $new_width = round($new_height*($src_width/$src_height));
    $new_x = round(($dst_width - $new_width)/2);
    $new_y = 0;
  }

  // Copy image on right place
  imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image , $new_x, $new_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $src_width, $src_height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gabrielle, my english is poorer than you. Let me help you to let you help yourself...

Actually the problem is with your `$thumbnail` handling which is being kept inside `scale_image` function in `$dst_image`, that is why it is repeating...

I tried writing (`imagepng($thumbnail,'images/image_xyzzz_i.png');`) `$thumbnail` and destroying it. The overlapping images were created. While I tried destroying `$dst_image` inside `scale_image` function, it destroyed `$thumbnail` too. Get rid of this relation.

**UPDATE....**

You can see it clearly that sprite is only affected by `$thumbnail` .

[image: Result For Thumbnail at different stages]

**UPDATE - 2**

Here is your modified code... Just two copy and pastes...

```
<?php

//////// PART 1 - DEFINE GLOBAL VARIABLES ////////

//// SPRITE IMAGES SOURCE ////
// 0 = Create sprite from memory - array()
// 1 = Create sprite from folder - glob()
$sprite_images_source = 0;

//// Use array as sprite images source ////
if($sprite_images_source == 0){
  $images=array(
    //// Example .PNGs ////
    // Orientation: Horizontal, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/128x72/444/f2f2f2.png&text=128x72.png',
    // Orientation: Horizontal, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/444/f2f2f2.png&text=1280x720.png',
    // Orientation: Vertical, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/72x128/444/f2f2f2.png&text=72x128.png',
    // Orientation: Vertical, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/720x1280/444/f2f2f2.png&text=720x1280.png',
    // Square, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/200x200/444/f2f2f2.png&text=400x400.png',

    //// Example .JPEGs ////
    // Orientation: Horizontal, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/128x72/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=128x72.jpg',
    // Orientation: Horizontal, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=1280x720.jpg',
    // Orientation: Vertical, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/72x128/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=72x128.jpg',
    // Orientation: Vertical, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/720x1280/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=720x1280.jpg',
    // Square
    'https://dummyimage.com/200x200/666/f2f2f2.jpg&text=200x200.jpg',

    //// Example .GIFs ////
    // Orientation: Horizontal, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/128x72/888/f2f2f2.gif&text=128x72.gif',
    // Orientation: Horizontal, bigger than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/888/f2f2f2.gif&text=1280x720.gif',
    // Orientation: Vertical, smaller than bounding box
    'https://dummyimage.com/72x128/888/f2f2f2.gif&text=72x128.gif',
    // Try to have 1/3/5/7 images to see empty space on sprite,
    // and test colorize sprite background method with this

  );

//// Use folder as sprite images source ////
} else if($sprite_images_source == 1){
 // $images = glob('sprite/images/*');
}


//// SINGLE THUMBNAIL = BOUNDING BOX DIMENSIONS ////
$thumbnail_width = 300;
$thumbnail_height = 300;
################# CUT LINE 1 FROM HERE ########################


//// SPRITE DIMENSIONS ////
$sprite_columns = 5;
$sprite_rows = ceil(count($images) / $sprite_columns);
$sprite_width = $thumbnail_width * $sprite_columns;
$sprite_height = $thumbnail_height * $sprite_rows;
$sprite = imagecreatetruecolor($sprite_width, $sprite_height);


//// SPRITE BACKGROUND COLOR ////
$sprite_bg = imagecolortransparent($sprite, imagecolorallocatealpha($sprite, 0,0,0,0));
imagefill($sprite,0,0,$sprite_bg);


//////// PART 2 - GENERATE SPRITE ////////

//// Assign each source from array to single image
foreach ($images as $i => $image) {
  $images[$i] = array(
    'src' => $image,
    'title' => 'Product ' . ($i + 1),
    'price' => '$' . ($i * 100)
  );
}


//// SINGLE THUMBNAIL MANIPULATION ////
// Start Generate Thumbnail from first file in array/folder
$i = 0;

for ($y = 0; $y < $sprite_height; $y += $thumbnail_height) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < $sprite_width; $x += $thumbnail_width) {
    // What is this for ???
    if ($i >= count($images)) {
      break 2;
    }


############################# PASTED LINE 1 HERE ######################
$thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
#######################################################################

    // Assosiate correct image for thumbnail from array
    $image = $images[$i];
    $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image['src']));

    // Scale Image to Bounding Box
    scale_image($src, $thumbnail, 'fit');


    //// PRINT IMAGE INTO SINGLE THUMBNAIL ////
    imagecopy($sprite, $thumbnail, $x, $y, 0, 0, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
    imagedestroy($src);
    $i++;

######################## PASTED LINE 2 HERE ###########################
imagedestroy($thumbnail);
#######################################################################

  }
  // END | for ($y = 0; $y < $sprite_height; $y += $thumbnail_height)
}
// END | for ($y = 0; $y < $sprite_height; $y += $thumbnail_height)


//////// PART 3 - OUTPUT SPRITE ////////

// Output Sprite to Browser as PNG
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($sprite);

// Clean up, and free memory
######################## CUT LINE 2 HERE ###########################
imagedestroy($sprite);


// FUNCTION - SCALE IMAGE
function scale_image($src_image, $dst_image, $op = 'fit') {
  $src_width = imagesx($src_image);
  $src_height = imagesy($src_image);

  $dst_width = imagesx($dst_image);
  $dst_height = imagesy($dst_image);

  // Try to match destination image by width
  $new_width = $dst_width;
  $new_height = round($new_width*($src_height/$src_width));
  $new_x = 0;
  $new_y = round(($dst_height-$new_height)/2);

  // FILL and FIT mode are mutually exclusive
  if ($op =='fill')
    $next = $new_height < $dst_height;
  else
    $next = $new_height > $dst_height;

  // If match by width failed and destination image does not fit, try by height
  if ($next) {
    $new_height = $dst_height;
    $new_width = round($new_height*($src_width/$src_height));
    $new_x = round(($dst_width - $new_width)/2);
    $new_y = 0;
  }

  // Copy image on right place
  imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image , $new_x, $new_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $src_width, $src_height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Vishal
I  need to try few times, but it works now, perfectly
I need to add thumbnail width and height inside loop to,
to make this work
What do you mean by: Get rid of this relation
Should i remove/change $dst_image inside function scale_image to?
There are 3 loops, foreach, for($y  and  for($x
should i put destroy($thumbnail) just once ??
I'm not familiar with cleaning memory - how can i check if its cleaned or not?
! MILION thank you for your help again , i'm freaking happy right now :))

Comment: Hi Gab, I have added the code with comment. Hope it will be clear now for you. See I have just moved two lines inside `for` loop.

Comment: Too see output of your sprites, comment the `header('Content-Type: image/png');` and change `imagedestroy($sprite);` to `imagedestroy($sprite,"images/sprite.png");`  after creating a images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line of code

```
$thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
```

After these lines and

```
    for ($y = 0; $y < $sprite_height; $y += $thumbnail_height) {
      for ($x = 0; $x < $sprite_width; $x += $thumbnail_width) {
        // What is this for ???
        if ($i >= count($images)) {
          break 2;
        }
################## MOVE THAT LINE HERE ##################
```

and do not forget to use

```
imagedestroy($thumbnail);
```

before loop ends.

Hope this helps to remove the overlapping images.

**UPDATE**
Your code is working and the problem was repeat of thumbnail handle. Here is resultant snap compared with that of my previous answer.

[image: Here is the success result compared to my previous answer...[1]]